# Storing data as a cookie in the browser vs. session

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cookies

I am trying to learn more about JAVA web development. I am mainly focused on trying to understand how data that a user enters, maybe through the course of filling out a multipage form, is managed as the user moves from page to page.

From what I have gathered, you can store data within the session on the server side. I am also learning about cookies which are stored within the browser. Is there a general rule that is used to determine what data should be stored in a cookie vs. when you should store data in a session (session.setAttribute), or are these completely different concepts?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basics of session/cookies are like this.

A session is typically a way for a server to store data about a user. This can be done in a variety of ways from memory, file to database.  This session can be used by you store pretty much anything you need to have as the user bounces around your site. It is assigned an ID (the session ID) which you don't usually need to worry about too much. In most web languages you can easily access the user session with some functions without dealing with IDs.

Now since the web is stateless - meaning there is really no way to know that user that visited page A is the same as the one that visited page B then we want to make sure that the user carries their session IDs with them. This can be done in a variety of ways but the most common one is through the use of a session cookie which is a special cookie automatically set by the server that is solely there for passing the session around. It can also be passed in the URL (I'm sure you've seen things like index.php?sessid=01223..) as well as headers and so on.

When most people talk about adding info to a cookie they are not talking about session cookies but about a custom cookie that you specifically set. The only reason that you would want to do that is if you needed to store info beyond the life of the session (which ends when the browser is closed). A good example of that is the "remember me" feature of many sites.

So use sessions unless you need to have something last a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There are a few rules actually. For one, cookie data is sent by the browser on every request; session data is kept on the server (and not re-transmitted every request). However, usually the session id is used with a coookie. This enables the server to identify the client.